# Laravel collection converts array to object

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-collection

If I run `$collection->filter(myFilter)`, Laravel does this annoying thing of adding keys to each model in the collection like so:

```
{
    "4": {
        "myObject": "data"
    },
    "7": {
        "myObject": "data"
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of the "4" and "7" so it's an array of my objects?

My code that runs is:

```
$obj = Cars::with('brand')->orderBy('id')->get();

return $obj->filter(function($value, $key)
{
    return $value->display == true;
});
```

Comment: I feel like `flatten()` might do what you're after, but you're going to need to provider some more example code to see how you're getting this output.

Comment: Yeah, `flatten()` should do the trick

Comment: @Dwight added code in - flatten worked. Feel free to add an answer for me to accept.

Comment: @tgun926 While `flatten()` happens to work in this case, `values()` is the appropriate method to use. I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue is that the `filter()` method does not rekey the underlying collection array. So, the Collection is still representing an array, it is just that your array looks like this:

```
[
    4 => Object4,
    7 => Object7,
]
```

While this is a perfectly valid array in PHP, this is not a proper array in JSON. Since this cannot be represented as an array in JSON, it is converted to an object in JSON.

In order to get this properly represented as an array in JSON, you just need to rekey the Collection array. The proper method for this is the `values()` method. All it does is call `array_values` on the underlying array. This will turn the above array in this:

```
[
    0 => Object4,
    1 => Object7,
]
```

Now, this is a proper numerically indexed array that JSON can understand and will treat as an array instead of an object.

While `flatten` may work for this particular case (your Collection is a collection of Eloquent Models), it is not actually the correct method, and may lead to unintended consequences. Additionally, it will perform a lot of extra logic that is not needed. Your best bet is to use the proper method for what you are trying to achieve, and that is the `values()` method.

```
$obj = Cars::with('brand')->orderBy('id')->get();

return $obj->filter(function($value, $key)
    {
        return $value->display == true;
    })
    ->values();
```

Comment: Ah yeah, @patricus is right - `values` is the correct method to use here, and as mentioned it should be more performant. Totally forgot about that method, good to be reminded. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @patricusMaybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488623/how-can-i-convert-array-two-dimensional-to-collection-laravel

Answer (score 5):

Calling `flatten()` on your collection should remove the keys and merge all their values up into a single collection.